# Overload Operator for Built-in Type in Dart

Tags: dart, operator-overloading

Consider the following Dart code:

```dart
class Vec2 {
  num x, y;
  Vec2(this.x, this.y);
  Vec2 operator*(num rhs) => Vec2(x * rhs, y * rhs);
  String toString() => "<$x, $y>";
}

void main() => print(Vec2(1, 2) * 3);
```

The output is as expected:

```
<3, 6>
```

However, this only works when the left-hand side of the expression is a `Vec2` and the right-hand side is a `num`. In this case, I want the multiplication operator to be commutative, so I write the following extension:

```dart
extension Vec2Util on num {
  Vec2 operator*(Vec2 rhs) => Vec2(rhs.x * this, rhs.y * this);
}
```

One might naturally expect the following code to produce identical output to the first snippet:

```dart
void main() {
  num x = 3;
  print("${x * Vec2(1, 2)}");
}
```

However, the compiler is instead reporting that `The argument type 'Vec2' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.` It looks as though the compiler is resolving the multiplication to `num operator*(num rhs)` in this case and then complaining that my `Vec2` can't be passed in as a `num` operand. Why does the compiler apparently disregard my extension? What is the correct way to create custom commutative operators like this?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.  Given a choice between a method that's formally defined in the class and an extension method, the class member will always win. (Otherwise extensions could break or subvert existing classes.)

Comment: Note that you could do `Vec2Util(x) * Vec2(1, 2)`, although that's obviously not as convenient as you want.

Comment: @jamesdlin The choice here is between two methods with differing signatures. What in the Dart standard prohibits this behavior? I know that Dart prohibits method overloading, but I wasn't aware that it applied to extension methods.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the signatures are different.  Dart doesn't support overloaded functions, so only the *name* matters.  When you have two methods with a conflicting name, the method that's "closer" to the type wins.  A method that the class itself defines therefore will always be the winner.  If you want a specific reference to the Dart specification, see section 13.2.2 (Applicability of an Extension) in the [Dart 2.15 draft](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf): "The type *S* does not have a member with the basename *m*..."

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the specification reference, that's exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want.

Dart user-definable binary operators are all methods on the first operand. Doing `e1 + e2` is *kind-of like* doing `e1.+(e2)` where `+` is the name of the method, except you can't normally call a method `+`.

In order to be able to do `3 * vector`, you need the method to be on `3`.

You can't add methods to other people's classes, not without fiddling with their source code, and `int` is a system class so even that is not possible.

You cannot use extension methods because extension methods do not apply when the receiver type already has an instance method with the same name.
And `int` defines *all* the operators.
(It's like, and definitely not coincidentally, that the user-definable operators were chosen from exactly what `int` needs. That's not new in Dart, the operators go back to C and Java.)

So, you can define an extension method on `int`, but you can't call it anyway, not without an override:

```dart
extension MyInt on int {
  Vector operator *(Vector other) => other.scalerMultiplication(this);
}
... MyInt(3) * vector ...
```

That's *more* complication than just swapping the operands.

Comment: `int` doesn't quite define *all* the available operators... there's also `operator []`/`operator []=`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Good point, it's the infix and prefix operators that are taken by `int`. I'll need to find a use for an extension `[]` on `int`. (C++ also has `operator ()`, what Dart just uses the `call` method for, but which acts like an operator syntactically, which is also not on `int`). How about `a[b]` being an iterator from `a` to `b`, inclusive, and `a(b)` being the same range, not including `b`. Or maybe not.